# How to set build optimization level when building PHP extension with phpize

Tags: php, c++, php-extension

I am writing a PHP extension in C++ using [this sample](http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/07/07/how-to-create-php-extensions-in-c-part-i-adding-simple-function/).

In Visual Studio project 'properties -> c/c++ -> optimization' I can set speed optimization (O2) or Full optimization(Ox).

As I imagine, in linux after running:

```
phpize 
./configure
```

Any suggestions where the optimization parameters should be set?

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to ask, and, I hate to sound negative BUT maybe you should do some reading before trying to tackle a problem like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably (I did not try, but this is how it usually goes) add additional compiler flags to the configure script when you run it. Export the flags you require first and rerun the regular compilation steps:

```
export CFLAGS="-O2"
# Just to make sure that the old files are removed:
phpize --clean
phpize
./configure
make
```

Instead of `-O2` you can obviously use an other optimization level as well.